# Should observer code always been wrapped in try catch

Tags: module, event-observer

Just as the title asks, should code inside an observer always be wrapped in a try catch?

I read this somewhere a long time ago and have always written observers in such this way since.

Is this considered good practice for magento modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the **same best practices do apply as for every other code** you write in Magento.

An observer is nothing else than a chance you get from Magento to insert your code at the position where the event gets dispatched (but without editing the core file).

If there is a chance an exception is thrown and by catching it you can solve the situation gracefully so that the request can be finished in a stable way, catch it.

If there cannot be an exception or there really shouldn't be one it may not be necessary to wrap everything in a try/catch-block.

Of course: you can always and everywhere put everything into such a block. But you don't because normally it's not necessary.

Another thing about oberserver: you may want to keep your **observer code as lean as possible** and use the observer to let other objects to the work (like models). Some people even strive for one-line or few-line observer methods (they put the actual code into models etc. for better testability).

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, if there is an exception thrown inside the observer and its not handled, it will break the whole process you are observing. So I would consider it a good practice to manage your own exceptions in these cases so that you won't break whatever else is going on.